# Parsear Csv en Php

Tags: php, csv

**Resulta que tengo este csv y es de las primeras veces que parseo uno tan "complejo" necesito saber una idea de como parsearlo en php.**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito crear un array asociativo con los datos del csv, pero el problema es que solo hay un encabezado en este caso Fecha, los números de al lado son los ids correspondientes a cada par de numeros.

array ejemplo:

Fecha => 01/02/2018
Id => 1
Licencia => 139 (Aquí habría que hacerle un split para separarlas)

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y que probaste hasta ahora? que tiene de complejo el parseo? que no te sale?

Answer (score 3):

Para parsear un csv en php podes utilizar la funcion [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) para obtener el contenido del archivo ya parseado en un array, si eso no es suficiente tambien tenes funciones para trabajar con strings [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) para separarlo en caso de que te venga ya en un string. 
Luego la asociacion de las fechas deberia ser sencilla utilizando un corte control iterando usando un [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) o un simple [`for`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php).